# Acceder a la propiedad C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
{
"customers": [
{
  "id": 1863630913636,
  "email": "cliente14.test14@example.com",
  "accepts_marketing": false,
  "created_at": "2019-07-08T15:22:25-05:00",
  "updated_at": "2019-07-08T15:22:26-05:00",
  "first_name": "Cliente14",
  "last_name": "test14",
  "orders_count": 0,
  "state": "enabled",
  "total_spent": "0.00",
  "last_order_id": null,
  "note": "IdType: Cédula de ciudadania\nID: 123456\n",
  "verified_email": false,
  "multipass_identifier": null,
  "tax_exempt": false,
  "phone": null,
  "tags": "",
  "last_order_name": null,
  "currency": "COP",
  "addresses": [],
  "accepts_marketing_updated_at": "2019-07-08T15:22:25-05:00",
  "marketing_opt_in_level": null,
  "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/Customer\/1863630913636"
 }}
```

Necesito acceder a solo el ID que está en la llave note:

```
 "note": "IdType: Cédula de ciudadania\nID: 123456\n",
```

Solo necesito obtener el valor, en este caso solo necesito:

```
123456
```

Estoy intentando de está manera obtener el solo ID:

```
foreach (customers oCliente in bp.customers)
{
    oBusinessPartner.LicTradNum = oCliente.note.ID;
}
```

Pero no logro conseguir el resultado esperado.

Comment: Que el responsable de ese Json arregle el formato, lo que está haciendo es sacrilegio... Por otro lado, te recomiendo que en vez de una imagen, coloques el código. Tiene mayor utilidad. Saludos

Comment: Yo tengo restricciones de red en mi trabajo y no puedo ver la imagen, no tengo idea de qué pasa :(

Answer (score 2):

Podrías tomar esto  **"note": "IdType: Cédula de ciudadania\nID: 123456\n"**, como un **STRING** y utilizar el método **SPLIT** para dividir el STRING por el delimitador **"\n"** ; con eso el método split te va devolver un arreglo de tamaño 2

```
string texto="note": "IdType: Cédula de ciudadania\nID: 123456\n";
string[] primerArreglo= texto.Split("\\n");

//esto tendrias de resultado
//primerArreglo[0]=  "note": "IdType: Cédula de ciudadania
//primerArreglo[1] = ID: 123456
```

y ahi puedes volver a aplicar el MÉTODO SPLIT al primerArreglo[1] , y como delimitador seria **":"** , con eso obtiene otro arreglo de tamaño 2

```
string[] segundoArreglo= primerArreglo[1].Split(":");

//esto tendrias de resultado
//segundoArreglo[0]=ID
//segundoArreglo[1]= 123456
```

y ahí ya tendrías el valor de ID en la variable segundoArreglo[1]

Comment: hay usuarios que ponen -1 , pero indiquen porque para aprender todos . Solo para criticar sirven algunos

Comment: Es cierto @Barckl3y solo ponen -1 y no aportan, si critican háganlo constructivamente explicando el por qué, así aprendemos todos.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @Barckl3y me ayudó bastante, al fin lo resolví con este bloque de código:

```
var documento = oCliente.note;
string[] primerArreglo = documento.Split('\n');
string[] segundoArreglo = primerArreglo[1].Split(':');
oBusinessPartner.FederalTaxID = segundoArreglo[1];
```

Comment: Si para cada uno de los `customers` el valor de `note` siempre sera de esa forma, entonces no tendras problema, pero... si ese contenido en algun momento cambia empezaras a obtener valos erroneos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una clase si conoces la estructura del json que llega, de esta forma:

```
public class Clase
{
    public Clase(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        prop1 = (string) jclas ["popiedadJson"];
        prop2 = (string) jclas ["popiedadJson"];
        prop3 = (string) jclas ["popiedadJson"];
        prop4 = (string) jclas ["popiedadJson"]
    }

    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
    public stringprop4  { get; set; }
}
```

Y asi lo puedes utilizar

```
    string json = @"{}";
    Clase objClase= new Clase(json);
```

accedes a las propiedades asi:

```
objClase.prop1 // aqui te van aparecer las propiedades que hayas declarado dentro de la clase
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `JObject`?  No he visto esa clase en .NET

Comment: `JObject` debe ser de la libreria [json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), siempre que en tus respuestas utilizes librerias que no venga con el framework debes agregar informacion de la misma.

Comment: Por cierto, la pregunta se refiere a como obtener un valor en particular de una cadena y no de como deserializar un json.

Comment: Si deserializas el Json puedes obtener el valor de la propiedad dado esto puedes obtener el valor que quieras